# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate on subdocument throw an validation error for ObjectId field

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a basic ChatRoom & ChatMessage schemas. For some sort of optimization, the ChatRoom contains `lastMessage` property as a subdocument of type ChatMessage.

```
export const ChatMessageSchema = new Schema({
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  chatRoomId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  createdBy: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  ...
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});

export const ChatRoomSchema = new Schema({
  membersIds: {
    type: [Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    required: true,
  },
  lastMessage: {
    type: ChatMessageSchema,
  },
  ...
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});
```

So whenever a new message is created I trying to update/replace the `lastMessage` prop with `findOneAndUpdate` like so.

```
const onChatMessagePosted = async ({ chatMessage, chatRoom }) => {
  // 1. Doesn't work, throw an "Path `chatRoomId` is required" error
  await ChatRoom.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: chatRoom._id },
    { $set: { lastMessage: chatMessage } },
    { new: true, runValidators: true },
  );

  // 2. It works
  chatRoom.set({ lastMessage: chatMessage });
  await chatRoom.save();

  // 3. It works too
  await ChatRoom.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: chatRoom._id },
    {
      $set: {
        'lastMessage._id': chatMessage._id,
        'lastMessage.chatRoomId': chatMessage.chatRoomId,
        'lastMessage.createdBy': chatMessage.createdBy,
        ...
      },
    },
    { new: true, runValidators: true },
  );
};
```

But for some reason, `findOneAndUpdate` throw a `path *propName* is required` error for subdocuments fields.

```
"errors": {
  "lastMessage.chatRoomId": {
    "message": "Path `chatRoomId` is required.",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "properties": {
      "message": "Path `chatRoomId` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "chatRoomId",
        "value": "5f72f8666144a40bb15f368a"
    },
    "kind": "required",
      "path": "lastMessage.chatRoomId",
      "value": "5f72f8666144a40bb15f368a"
  },
  "lastMessage.createdBy": {
    "message": "Path `createdBy` is required.",
      "name": "ValidatorError",
      "properties": {
      "message": "Path `createdBy` is required.",
        "type": "required",
        "path": "createdBy",
        "value": "5ec65435dd1b860d9898609b"
    },
    "kind": "required",
      "path": "lastMessage.createdBy",
      "value": "5ec65435dd1b860d9898609b"
  }
},
"message": "Validation failed: lastMessage.chatRoomId: Path `chatRoomId` is required., lastMessage.createdBy: Path `createdBy` is required.",
```

The confusing parts are:

- It only throws for fields where `type: Schema.Types.ObjectId` (In this example `lastMessage.message` prop pass validation);
- It doesn't throw for mongoose `save` method;
- It doesn't throw is using subpath fields;

Is it expected mongoose behavior? And if there is any way to make it work without update each subdocument field or without save method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem comes from the [Refs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). You should add the ref of ChatMessageSchema under the ChatRoomSchema. Try this:

chatMessage.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ChatMessageSchema = new Schema({
  message: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  chatRoomId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  createdBy: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
  },
  ...
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('ChatMessage', ChatMessageSchema);
```

chatRoom.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ChatRoomSchema = new Schema({
  membersIds:[
      { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Member' }
    ],
  lastMessage: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ChatMessage'
  },
  ...
}, {
  timestamps: true,
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('ChatRoom', ChatRoomSchema);
```

Comment: The refs are present. I omitted them to make the code sample smaller. Sorry if it confused you. Also, there is no problem with `lastMessage` as a `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`. But in my case, it would be better to have it as a subdocument.

Comment: Oups ! ok no worry... can you show me what chatMessage instance is containing ?